# Load into table 'users' failed. Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details, Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

try:
cur.execute("""
copy users
from 's3://mybucketxxx/SampleCSVFile_119kb_Copy.csv'
credentials 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::78942xxx:role/redshift-s3-access'
delimiter ','
region 'ap-south-1'
""")

except psycopg2.Error as e:
print("Error: Coming")
print(e)

Errors: Load into table 'users' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1):

That is a Redshift error - possibly due to a syntax error in the COPY command or I'm the format of the S3 file (but it could be any number of errors).

Stl_load_errors is a table that holds the details of COPY commands that error.  Issuing a SQL command like:

```
select * from stl_load_errors order by starttime desc limit 10;
```

This will show the information for the last 10 COPY commands that had errors.

If this information isn't clear update the question with the in information for your query and the community can help further.

Comment: command like - select * from stl_load_errors order by starttime desc limit 1 -- this query return --

Load into table 'users' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details. 
100, 0, 106421, datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 19, 13, 25, 5, 12204), 1073995907, 2466, 's3://mybucket5008/SampleCSVFile_119kb_Copy.csv ', 1, 'userid ', 'int ', '0   ', 0, '1,Meerut', '1,Meerut ', 1214, 'Delimiter not found ', 0, 0, 0)

Comment: If you line up the data you got back with the column names of stl_load_errors you’ll see that the ‘err_reason’ is ‘Delimiter not found’.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html. The field it is not parsing is ‘1,Meerut’.  It is possible that the issue is with the quoting in the CSV file.